# Dynamic loading in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a question about Extjs

I have read the official document on Sencha doc but I have some confusions about the dynamic loading.

What is the difference between new X() and Ext.create('X')? Which should be used and when?

Any answer are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never ever use new in ExtJS. if you use dynamic loading with `Ext.create('X')` ExtJS will check if the class `X` is already loaded and will load it before internally create the class with new.